# updating 2 800 000 records with 4 threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a VB.net application with an Access Database with one table that contains about 2,800,000 records, each raw is updated with new data daily. The machine has 64GB of ram and i7 3960x and its over clocked to 4.9GHz.

Note: data sources are local.

I wonder if I use ~10 threads will it finish updating the data to the rows faster.

If it is possiable what would be the mechanisim of deviding this big loop to multiple threads?

Update: Sometimes the loop has to repeat the calculation for some row depending on results also the loop have exacly 63 conditions and its 242 lines of code.

Comment: Chances are good that the bottleneck is not processing power but IO - in such a case adding threads will only _slow_ things down due to synchronisation overheads.

Comment: so there is not way to make it faster?

Comment: @user1590636 increase IO throughput. An SSD would certainly help.

Comment: Using a database designed for high loads would also help - SQL Server Express should be better than Access for this.

Comment: @vcsjones already using and SSD

Comment: What library are you accessing the database through? ADO.Net? LinqToSql? Entity Framework? Something else. Many of these frameworks are simply not geared for bulk updates, and will be slow regardless of how many threads you throw at the problem. Can you show any code?

Comment: well i don't know what are you talking about since i am just a Product Manager with very basic programming skills :D, but i use OleDB commands to update a datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Access is not particularly good at handling many concurrent updates, compared to other database platforms.

The more your tasks need to do calculations, the more you will typically benefit from concurrency / threading.  If you spin up 10 threads that do little more than send update commands to Access, it is unlikely to be much faster than it is with just one thread.

If you have to do any significant calculations between reading and writing data, threads may show a performance improvement.

I would suggest trying the following and measuring the result:

- One thread to read data from Access
- One thread to perform whatever calculations are needed on the data you read
- One thread to update Access

You can implement this using a Producer / Consumer pattern, which is pretty easy to do with a [BlockingCollection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/08/12/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem.aspx).

The nice thing about the Producer / Consumer pattern is that you can add more producer and/or consumer threads with minimal code changes to find the sweet spot.

**Supplemental Thought**

IO is probably the bottleneck of your application.  Consider placing the Access file on faster storage if you can (SSD, RAID, or even a RAM disk).

Comment: would a RamDisk make a difference if i am already using SSD, will multithreading do a difference on a ram disk?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  I have a modern (fast) SSD and recently moved a SQL Server 2008 R2 .mdf file to a RAM disk and it was almost exactly twice as fast.

Comment: If you want a RAM disk software recommendation, I use http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/primo-ramdisk/index.html because of its flexibility.

Comment: the Progress bar seems to be going a little bit faster with the database and the application loaded to a ram disk, but its not that much difference, also i've added some info to the question :)

Comment: Regarding the extra information... hard to tell from that how much a thread dedicated to CPU tasks would help.  Run your code through a profiler (the one built into VS2010 works fine) and see how much time you are spending in each part of your code.

Comment: i have vs 2010 proffisional which does not include a profiler..i started using threads already but each thread works on a datatable but i dont know how to combine the datatables and load them to the datagridview...thread1 works on the first 400,000 records, thread2 works on reords from 400,001 to 800,000 and so on.

Comment: You can at least get a free trial for one of the paid profilers.  RedGate's is one of the better ones.  Personally I have not worked much with data tables, so I can't give advice on that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're updating 2,800,000 records with 2,800,000 queries, it will definitely be slow.

Generally, it's good to avoid opening multiple connections to update your data.

You might want to show us some code of how you're currently doing it, so we could tell you what to change.

So I don't think (with the information you gave) that going multi-thread for this would be faster. Now, if you're thinking about going multi-thread because the update freezes your GUI, now that's another story.

If the processing is slow, I personally don't think it's due to your servers specs. I'd guess it's more something about the logic you used to update the data.

Comment: there are 22 columns and i just do calculations and change the datatable, calculations are really basic, but i wonder if breaking the database to multiple datatables then make each thread update one table then merge he tables when all threads are done...

Comment: no i already use background worker so the GUI is not freezing

Answer (score 0):

Don't wonder, test. Write it so you could dispatch as much threads to make the work and test it with various numbers of threads. What does the loop you are talking about look like?

With questions like "if I add more threads, will it work faster"? it is always best to test, though there are rule of thumbs. If the DB is local, chances are that Oded is right.

Comment: The Loop updates the column numbers 4 to 13 with new numerical data after that it does some calculations on the new data and fills the results in the columns left the it colors the row in the datagrid depending on results